# Angular 2 not re-rendering until I click the page?

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

On this page [here](https://www.findchildcare.co.nz/login).

It's possible to see that the Facebook login button is **initially disabled**. (Using `[disabled]="myProperty"`)

Once an API request `/facebooklogin/isnewuser` returns, **it is enabled**.

Everything works fine. However, the button won't be **re-rendered until I click on the page**.

I've also noticed that this happens with most things involving the data-binder in Angular.

- Is this intended behavior?
- Is there anyway around this?
- Is this specific to Angular?

Tested on Firefox & Chrome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that for some reason change detection isn't happening as it should. You can "force" it with **[`NgZone`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html)** or manually trigger change detection with **[`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)**:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core' 

constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

and then run `detectChanges()` after setting your variable:

```
// whatever you are using to disable/enable button
this.myProperty = false;
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

or the use of `NgZone`:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core' 

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}
```

and add something like the following where you are enabling the button:

```
// whatever you are using to disable/enable button
this.ngZone.run(() => {this.myProperty = false})
```

I can't say anything more to as why this is happening. I have noticed that once in while these things happen for no apparent reason, this seems to be one of those cases. If anyone has some insight on this, please do tell. Haven't come upon anyone who has been able to explain this, yet :)